# Latex interpreter + enlarge font size in MATLAB lower text resolution in plot

Tags: matlab, latex, matlab-figure

I have been using the [`shadedErrorBar`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26311-shadederrorbar) while plotting, and the part of the code since I use `shadedErrorBar` reads as follows:

```
plot1 = shadedErrorBar(tau_vec, mean(deg_20_hubs_0), sd_deg_20_hubs_0, 'b-o', 1);   hold on;
plot2 = shadedErrorBar(tau_vec, mean(deg_20_hubs_1), sd_deg_20_hubs_1, 'r-o', 1);
plot3 = shadedErrorBar(tau_vec, mean(deg_40_hubs_0), sd_deg_40_hubs_0, 'b-x', 1);
plot4 = shadedErrorBar(tau_vec, mean(deg_40_hubs_1), sd_deg_40_hubs_1, 'r-x', 1);
hold off;
set(gca, 'FontSize', 15);
xlabel('$\log_2 C_\tau$', 'Interpreter', 'latex'); ylabel('ExNVI');
xlim([-13, 13]);
ylim([0, 1]);

I=legend('$\bar{d}=20$; no hub   ', '$\bar{d}=20$; with_hubs   ', '$\bar{d}=40$; no hub   ', '$\bar{d}=40$; with hubs   ', ...
'Location', 'SouthWest');
set(I, 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'fontsize', 15);

if(off_diag==10 && N==500)
    set(I, 'visible', 'on');
else
    set(I, 'visible', 'off');
end

box on;
set(gca,'units','centimeters');
pos = get(gca,'Position');
ti = get(gca,'TightInset');

set(gcf, 'PaperUnits','centimeters');
set(gcf, 'PaperSize', [pos(3)+ti(1)+ti(3)+0.6 pos(4)+ti(2)+ti(4)+0.6]);
set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode', 'manual');
set(gcf, 'PaperPosition',[0 0 pos(3)+ti(1)+ti(3)+0.6 pos(4)+ti(2)+ti(4)+0.6]);

saveas(fig, sprintf('./output/offdiag_%d_N_%d.pdf', off_diag, N));
```

The resulting plot has low resolution texts like this:

[image]
But the resolution of the curve is fine. The problem disappears when I tried removing the latex interpreter, but is it possible to keep it and fix the resolution? I did the plot under MATLAB 2014b in Windows.

Many thanks!

Comment: perhaps a bit overkill, but I am quite sure, that this will give you a proper solution:[undocumented matlab-> export_fig](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/export_fig)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set(gcf, 'renderer','painters');
```

will solve the problem. It will render the figure as vector graphic, which is the better choice since you're using the pdf format. Also specify the resolution using the `print` command instead of `saveas`:

```
print(fig, '-dpdf', '-r600', 'myFigure.pdf')
```

Comment: If it does not work, please edit your question with example data to make your problem reproducable.

Comment: Thanks @thewaywewalk for the answer! The `painters` renderer doesn't work with shadedErrorBar package but the second one -- the `print` command works well.